# batch network monitoring per process/socket (Linux, shell)

Tags: linux, networking, process, monitoring

I am looking for a quick tool to batch monitoring network traffic per socket and/or per process.

I.e., I would like to iterate over a given time and get the iterated traffic as text output/on stdout.

I checked several tools so far as iftop, nethogs, iptraf-ng, ifstat, tcptrack -- which offer either nice statistics of the info I look for or a batch mode, but I did not find a way to combine it.

Ideally, it would be something like iftop or nethogs (or iptraf) just with a batch option
ala

```
iftop -i eth# -iterateinsec 60 > nettraf.txt
```

Is there a way to do so (maybe with the tools I tried and missed its batch feature) or some other ready available tool?

Cheers and thanks,
  Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Sealion](https://sealion.com/) which is very simple use. There are default set of commands which will give you all statistics in a given timeline. Also you can add parameters to it.

[image]